# ruby 1.9.2 installation and gems

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed Ruby 1.9.2 from source.  But it seems there is some trouble recognizing the bundler gem which I have already installed.

My `/etc/environment` file:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/ruby/bin"
```

It looks like my gems are in `/usr/local/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/`.
In my rails application when I attempt to run sudo bundle install I get an error:

```
sudo: bundle: command not found
```

Also, why do the directories say 1.9.1?

Comment: try rvm... (on mac)  it is quite reliable

Comment: rvm on Mac and *nix is quite reliable, not just Macintosh.

Answer (score -1):

Type `which ruby` to see the path your system thinks ruby is in.

Did you use a `--prefix=...` option for configure when you set up the configuration? Normally Ruby from source wouldn't be in /usr/local/ruby/bin. The Ruby executable would be in /usr/local/bin/ruby, but that is not how you'd set up your PATH to use it, so that looks suspicious. Notice that your path already contains `/usr/local/bin` so if Ruby installed into the normal location for a source-installation, that path will pick it up and your final search of `/usr/local/bin/ruby` will be wrong and unnecessary.

If you installed the gem before you installed the new version of Ruby then the gem would be part of the previous installation, not the current one, and wouldn't be visible to it. They're separate installs.

Unless you are trying to do a system-wide install for multiple users there is no real reason to compile from source and allow it to install to /usr/local/bin. I highly recommend installing RVM, then letting it install any Ruby versions into RVM's `~/.rvm` sandbox. Gems will also be installed relative to the currently enabled RVM controlled ruby, which is a really good thing.